# javaScript function doesn't work in first time click

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to invoke a JavaScript function (that have some php code ) when clicking a button..
but the function doesn't work in first time!! I should click two times to make it start.
here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function f1(id)
{
    document.getElementById("hiddenVal").value = id;
    window.alert("the function is started");
    window.alert(id);
    f2();
}
function f2()
{
    <?php
        $Biid=$_POST["hiddenVal1"];
    ?>
    window.alert("<?php echo $Biid; ?>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form  method="post">
        <button id="2" onclick="f1(this.id)"> click me </button>
        <input type="text"  name="hiddenVal1" id="hiddenVal" /> </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a dodgy `</div>` hanging around in that code without a starting `<div>`

Comment: I think you've got this all wrong, there is no PHP on the client side (the side that monitors clicking the element), that means that the `$_POST["hiddenVal1"]` value has to be set before the page is generated because all the PHP code will run on the server side to generate client side code.

Comment: **Note** there is NO `$_POST` array until the form has been submitted !!!! So `f2()` will have NO VALUE FOR `$_POST["hiddenVal1"]` and therefore the whole premise for this code falls down

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you tell me how to fix it, I'm a beginner and I really need help

Comment: Try `onclick="f1(this.id); return false;"`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the default behavior of a button inside a form is to submit that form
So you can add a type attribute to the button so it won't submit the form or use a event listener with a "preventDefault" function just like this:

Option 1:

```
<button id="2" type="button" onclick="f1(this.id)"> click me </button>
```

Option 2:

```
document.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  f1(event.target.id);
});
```

Comment: I changed the button to <input type="submit" id="2"> and wrote the document.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  f1(event.target.id);
}); , but it didn't fix my problem. do you have another solution